# Create PubSub topic for external third party consumer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a cloud service for remotely controlling devices which also offers third party clients to create OAuth2 apps so that they can integrate our service with theirs through an API we expose.

The thing is that we would like to make an asynchronous service for publishing changes to our third party clients instead of them polling to our servers every X seconds.

We were evaluating the use of Google cloud Pub/Sub. Our idea consists that for each OAuth2 third party app created, we create a Google Cloud pub/sub topic for them. We would delegate to the client the creation of a subscription that will consume those messages using pull/push style. But we have multiple doubts about this approach:

- How will the pricing work? ideally, third party clients should be the one paying for the notifications service; the cost will depend on the traffic and number of events they consume.
- Once I create a topic in my account, how can I open the topic so that only a specific user (the third party client) is able to create a subscription to listen to events from that topic?

Our solution would require the above conditions. I don't really know if Google Pub/sub service can meet them.

Another approach is to delegate the creation of the topic and the subscription to the third party client, and for them to hand us some publish access credentials so that we are able to publish events to such topic.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you evaluate the webhook pattern? Create for them a push subscription and publish the notification to their HTTPS endpoint.

Comment: Yes, it could be an option, but it will mean that I would need to handle cases when the endpoint is unreachable, how many retries, how many days should I hold on to an undelivered message... Google Pub/Sub handles all those things for me

Comment: Yes, create a push subscription that push to an external webhook. PubSub will handle the retry for you.

Comment: Hi @GabrielRequenaGarcía, did the above comment help?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, I didn''t get to try it, got caught up with other stuff. But definately I must try it. Did you get to try it?

Comment: For your requirement, the billing will be considered according to the project which is containing the topic and the subscription. For giving permission to third party, you can consider using [OAuth 2.0](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#strategies). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Ok so I've got back to this just now, but still I haven't found a solution. My requirement is that the topic and the subscription is handled by a third party (so that they take care of the billing), and that they configure me some kind of authentication (or an endpoint) that allows me (a third aparty user) to create events in that topic ( I will be the publisher).